# Ubuntu 12.04 boots up into terminal (Lightdm & Ati Video card)

Tags: boot, command-line, lightdm, fglrx

I just returned from a two-week vacation and started up my laptop, everything went fine and it installed a lot of updates (including a kernel update. sorry for few details, I didn't really pay attention to what it did update).

The next time I tried to start up the machine, it wouldn't. Among the last messages there was e4rat, and when the automatic package repair (in ubuntu-repair-mode or whatever it's called in English - fortunately, that works) wanted to replace it with ureadahead, I figured there'd be some kind of incompatibility with the newest kernel.

So I removed it myself (as the automatic repair wasn't able to. Did it using `sudo apt-get install ureadahead ubuntu-minimal` , which worked fine), and manually removed the e4rat-preload-line in grub.

Problem is: It won't show the login-screen but instead it switches to tty1, prompting me to log in. When looking at tty7, it only shows me the usual startup-messages of what was started last (no error messages visible).

Running `sudo service lightdm (re)start` freezes the entire system, same when trying to run gdm.
According to the xorg.log file, fglrx works fine (no error messages).

/var/log/lightdm/lightdm.log states:

> [+0.16s] DEBUG: Launching process 1257: /usr/bin/X :0 -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:0 -nolisten tcp vt7 -novtswitch -background none
>
> ....
>
> [+0.73s] DEBUG: Process 1257 exited with return value 127
> [+0.73s] DEBUG: X server stopped

/var/log/lightdm/x-0.log states:

> (WW) fglrx: No matching Device section for instance (BusID PCI:0@1:0:1) found
>
> /usr/bin/X: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/fglrx_drv.so: undefined symbol: GlxInitVisuals2D

I already deleted (after backing it up) the xorg.conf file to avoid misconfiguration.

Edit:
/var/log/syslog states:

> Jul 12 16:22:29 Lutz kernel: [   24.014008] init: lightdm main process (1213) terminated with status 1

Any ideas?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Forgot to mention, I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS!

Comment: Did some more research, the fglrx driver I'm using seems fine according to the xorg log file (no error messages).

Comment: Thanks for researching the problem before asking. Also, thanks for all of the detail you gave. :-)

Answer (score 3):

It looks like your Login Manager does not load up. Can you verify this with:

```
# ps aux | grep lightdm
```

If it only outputs the grep itself then LightDM is not running. You could try:

```
# service lightdm restart
```

If you are using lightdm of course, in Gnome this is GDM, KDE uses KDM, LXDE uses LXDM. etc..

Also if this continues to occur you should do a:

```
# runlevel
```

and see it the init level is the right value, I believe it is supposed to be 2 or higher at least.

I hope this helps steer you in the right direction.

Kind regards,
Jochen

Comment: Thank you for your support. Unfortunately, lightdm seems to be started up, and restarting it freezes the entire system (complete freeze). Run level returns N 2.

Comment: I found out some more. See above for the info.

Comment: Does it literally freeze your entire system or does the screen simply go black? Since if there is an issue with your Video-Card drivers it might be that X no longer functions properly.

Comment: Nevermind, just saw you fixed it. Happy to hear that. I have had such an issue as well in the past.

Answer (score 2):

I solved it.

The problem was that I installed fglrx manually (not using the official repositories, but via direct download from AMD) and that some update was incompatible to my older version of fglrx. So using a USB thumb drive ubuntu, I downloaded the newest fglrx-driver and installed it from shell; everything's working fine again now.

All help appreciated.