# How can I leave tty?

Tags: gnome, sdl

So I got a problem here. So I installed SDL 2.0.1, everything worked fine, I installed dependencies of sdl as well, so I saw that it didn't worked, so I rebooted my pc, after that I get to gnome, and don't know what do, maybe some help? :)

Comment: What do you want to do exactly?

Comment: I want to get back to the main display of Ubuntu, I just got a console of Gnome, and I don't know how to get back from it... For example I need to enter my login and password in console, and just do terminal things.

Comment: Errr... Do you mean [Unity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Ubuntu_13.04_Desktop.png)? Or [tty](http://img.scoop.it/fQJBWDXZz4N-iAiZto85CTl72eJkfbmt4t8yenImKBVvK0kTmF0xjctABnaLJIm9)? :-)

Comment: I mean I got to tty, and I want to get to Unity if it is the main explorer or I don't know how to call it, sorry for my bad dictionary of ubuntu definitions, I'am very new to this. :)

Comment: Okay, here is what the problem is. I'am at tty, and I want to get back to Unity. Every time I reboot I get to tty, how to fix it?

Comment: Question [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/162727/ubuntu-12-04-boots-up-into-terminal-lightdm-ati-video-card) on it...

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know definitions yet, as I said I'am very new to this, so I couldnt formulate normal question.

Comment: Don't Mind... Everyone has to start somewhere - Does any of the below work for you :-)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Normally, can enter a tty with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+(<kbd>F1</kbd>-<kbd>F12</kbd>), and in Ubuntu, and can exit it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>. This problem is probably due to the login manager not starting. Try:

```
sudo service lightdm start
```

for the default lightdm login manager, and this for Gnome's login manager:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/gdm start
```

You can also try entering the user session directly:

```
startx
```

<sub>Pleases note that some of the above may be guesswork...</sub>

Comment: Okay I managed to fix it, when I tried startx It worked, but before that I needed to reinstall my xorg server, because it was broken or something.

Comment: I would recommend getting the login manager working (the bit you normally see to login), as that runs background elements like the screensaver and stuff.